# YouTube comment notifications don't clear after I read them

Tags: youtube, notifications, comments

When someone replies to my comment on YouTube, I get a notification. But, when I view what has been posted, and I even reply to it, the notification is still there!

This is the part of the website I'm talking about:

[image: comment notification on youtube]

After some time, however, it does clear, but not all of it, and I'm not sure what triggers it.

I can go to the actual inbox, and delete everything, then indeed it does disappear, but why doesn't it disappear when I view them in the "comments" section of my inbox?

Comment: Same issue here!

Comment: Seems more like an intended feature, it would be noticed as it seems to be quite a big issue...

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t3ZoZcAs64Q
I made a video addressing this problem, please pardon my little intro in the beginning :P

Comment: This works, thank you. I honestly don't understand how can they keep such a bug alive so long...

Comment: Please update your answer, the video link is dead.

Comment: Hey, @hawkeyeheo, could you please write an answer I could accept?

Answer (score -1):

You may have two logins with your account—e.g. you may have Chrome and IE and have logged into them both at the same time; doesn't matter if one screen is closed because you are logged in online.

If it still doesn't work, I can’t help you but when I started to use Chrome, I had my YouTube on IE still logged in and the inbox notifications wouldn't go away until I looked at them as well as the ones on Chrome. After you do that, log off your leased used browser and that's it. This is just my experience.

Comment: I am logged in on a couple of machines and mobile phones, but this isn't logical: it shouldn't matter. Computers just don't work that way, they would explicitly have to check what am I using and then update their database accordingly, and this makes no sense. But I'll try it and see...

Comment: just wondering did it work?